# Transform numpy 2d array like GIMP/Photoshop canvas

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a 3D numpy array, where I threat it like a 2D array with multiple layers. In the example below, I have 2 layer 2d array, with width 4 and height 3.

```
import numpy
mapTiles=numpy.array(([[1,1,1,1],
                    [1,1,1,1],
                    [1,1,1,1]],
                   [[2,0,2,2],
                    [0,0,2,2],
                    [0,0,0,2]]))
```

I need to transform this numpy array in a similar way to Gimp/Photoshop/Aseprite canvas. So using height, width, and vertical and horizontal offset values.

- If the resulting array is bigger, keep dimensions aligned top/left and fill with zeroes.
- If the resulting array is smaller, just cut.
- If the offset falls outside of width and height limit, just cut. Fill empty spaces with zeroes.

I could only conceive this with lots of `if` conditions, below is just one of the possible cases. Is there any already made specialized method for this? To create a new array and copy over, is there an alternative to just use `for`?

```
mapResize(mapTiles, width,height,offsetx=0,offsety=0):
    if(width-offsetx < len(mapTiles[0][0]) and height-offsety < len(mapTiles[0])):
        x=min(max(offsetx,0),len(mapTiles[0][0]))
        y=min(max(offsety,0),len(mapTiles[0]))
        return mapTiles[:,y:(y+height),x:(x+width)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does it (next time try to show expected output):

```
def mapResize(m, w, h, xo, yo):
    pads=((0,0),(abs(yo),abs(yo)+h),(abs(xo),abs(xo)+w))
    bigMap=np.lib.pad(m,pads,'constant',constant_values=0)
    return bigMap[:,yo+abs(yo):yo+abs(yo)+h,xo+abs(xo):xo+abs(xo)+w]

mapResize(mapTiles,3,5,1,-2)
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 2, 2],
        [0, 2, 2],
        [0, 0, 2]]])
```

Basically, make a big padded array and slice it to size.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the new array then copy the data into it. This will require slices to be set up for both the source and the destination arrays.

```
new_tiles = numpy.zeros((2, height, width), dtype=mapTiles.dtype)
_, src_height, src_width = mapTiles.shape
# Source x:
start = max(0, -offsetx)
stop = max(0, width - offsetx)  # Going too large here is harmless
src_x_slice = slice(start, stop)

# Source y:
start = max(0, -offsety)
stop = max(0, height - offsety)
src_y_slice = slice(start, stop)

# Dest x:
start = max(0, offsetx)
stop = max(0, offsetx + src_width)  # Going past the end is harmless
dest_x_slice = slice(start, stop)

# Dest y:
start = max(0, offsety)
stop = max(0, offsety + src_height)
dest_y_slice = slice(start, stop)

new_tiles[:, dest_y_slice, dest_x_slice] = mapTiles[:, src_y_slice, src_x_slice]
```